# The composition f ◦ · · · ◦ f (n times) bijective => f is bijective, if there is an n for every x.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am not sure my proof is correct/complete for the following:

For a function $f : A \to A$ denote by $f^n$
the composition $f \circ \cdots \circ f$ ($n$ times). Show that if for each
$x\in A$ there is an $n(x) \in \mathbb N$ such that $f^n(x) = x$, then $f$ is bijective.

Proof: We see that $f \circ \cdots \circ f(x) = x$ is a linear and thus a bijective function.

Notes:
Given 2 functions $f$ and $g$, if $g \circ f$ is injective, then $f$ is injective.

Also, if $g \circ f$ is surjective, then $g$ is surjective.

Therefore,
$f^n = f^{n-1} \circ f = x$ is bijective therefore injective and thus $f$ is injective for every given $x$ in $A$

$f^n = f \circ f^{n-1} = x$ is bijective and thus surjective and by the notes above, $f$ is surjective for every given $x$ in $A$

We conclude $f$ is bijective.

Comment: What does "linear" have to do with the question?

Comment: Your last two sentences are false: what is the meaning of "$f^n = x$" in both cases?

Comment: @JCAA, my logic was since function f(x)=x f:A-> A is linear it is bijective.

Comment: $f(x)\ne x{}{}{}{}{}{}$ for some (or even all $x$).

Comment: my bad ∘⋯∘()= is linear and thus bijective

Comment: That is also not true. Your condition only says that for every $x$ there **exists** $n$ such that $f^n(x)=x$. The $n$ depends on $x$.

Comment: Yes, this is what I was unsure of and why posted this. However, since  ∘   is injective and potentially we have a different g for every x as you mentioned, why can't we have f is injective at every x? This rule is not depending on variations of g.

Comment: I proved the statement in my answer.

Comment: Yes you did. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof. The function $f$ is surjective because $f(...(f(x))...)=x$ for every $x$. Suppose that $f$ is not injective, $f(a)=f(b)$ for some $a\ne b$. We have that $f^n(a)=a, f^m(b)=b$.Then $f^{mn}(a)=a\ne b=f^{mn}(b)$. But
then $a=f^{mn}(a)=f^{mn-1}(f(a))=f^{mn-1}(f(b))=f^{mn}(b)=b$, a contradiction.

Hence $f$ is bijective.

Comment: . . . n I c e. .

Comment: I see. Thanks. I missed $f^{n}(f^{m}) = f^{mn}$

Comment: That is not true: $f^n(f^m(x))=f^{m+n}(x)$.

Comment: Yes, $f^{mn} = f^{n} \bigcirc f^{n} \bigcirc ...\bigcirc f^{n} $ m times